# Can't archive without device in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning

I'm trying to distribute an iOS app without having a device. I did purchase a developer account and set up signing and provisioning profiles for distribution.

I can see my profiles in Xcode. But when I choose the "Archive" menu item, Xcode reports "No provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found."

and suggests I click on "Fix issue" to download one. But then I get "Unable to create a provisioning profile because your team has no devices registered in the Member Center. Please connect a device, enable it for development, and add it to the Member Center using the Organizer."

My problem is similar to [Could I submit app to appstore without ios device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724654/could-i-submit-app-to-appstore-without-ios-device). But I have a provisioning profile. Interestingly Clocksmiths question to AmitApollo's answer seems to be spot on but doesn't have an answer.

Comment: @rmaddy, could you unduplicate this question please? I explained why it is different.

Comment: Done. But it's a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811551/error-when-trying-to-create-archive-of-ios-app-unable-to-create-a-provisioning