# How to "select a team" when Xcode thinks I'm not a registered iOS developer? Also, do I need an iPhone to get a provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

When I try to create an archive for my finished app, I get this message:

> No non-expired provisioning profiles were found. Xcode can resolve
>   this issue by downloading a new provisioning profile from the
>   Membership Center.

I click `Fix Issue`.

I then get:

> The selected team doesn't have an iOS Developer Program membership.
>   Select a team with an iOS Developer Program membership and try again.

I *do* have an iOS developer program membership but I can't figure out how to "select a team." I've looked around and can't find any resources on how to correct this. Anyone else had this problem?

**Edit:**

When I go to `Project > General > Identity > Team`, my account is correctly associated with the app, and it says that I have an iOS developer membership. Yet no provisioning profile and the above errors persist.

**Edit2:**

When I click `Fix Issue` beneath "Team" in the Identity section of `Project > General`, to correct the lack of provisioning profile, I get a different error:

> Unable to create a provisioning profile because your team has no
>   devices registered in the Member Center. Please connect a device,
>   enable it for development, and add it to the Membership Center using
>   the Organizer.

I have a Mac, but no iPhone....does that mean I can't publish the app? Or can I use the Mac? How do I add it? I don't see any option in the organizer.

Comment: Generally when I start getting provisioning issues in Xcode, I remove my account via Preferences, shut down Xcode, reopen and add my account again.  Why that works for me, I have no idea.  YMMV

Comment: Go to Xcode > Preferences > Accounts. Make sure your Apple Id is there. Is your team listed for your Apple Id?

Comment: See edits, I think...

Comment: Does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811551/error-when-trying-to-create-archive-of-ios-app-unable-to-create-a-provisioning

Comment: I didn't think you could even create an archive without a device attached...

Comment: @AdamPro13 I didn't either, but I found that answer when I was researching if something had changed...

Comment: @BradBrighton THANK YOU, it did ultimately lead me to a working archive, although there were still several steps after that. This process is so convoluted and difficult, it's the absolute opposite of Apple's normal UX for end-users. Oh my god that literally took me 2 months. Everytime I tried I hit so many errors involving provisioning profiles, CSRs, keychains, accounts, and permissions that I just couldn't bare to keep going and had to walk away for another two weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your last remaining road block

> Unable to create a provisioning profile because your team has no
>   devices registered in the Member Center. Please connect a device,
>   enable it for development, and add it to the Membership Center using
>   the Organizer.

You need to register a device.  If you do not own one, find a friend or relative and ask them to allow you to register their device.  It will not create any issues for them.  You do not need the device after that for archiving, it just needs to be registered so a profile can be generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the device to be a `generic iOS device`. When I was running an archive with my iPhone as the default target, I would get the team error that you are receiving. Changing this to `generic iOS device` solved this issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly you have to purchase iOS Developer Program.(its cost is 99$ Per Year.)

1. You must Registered For Apple Developer Program.
2. Then Create app id for Your Application.
3. Then Create Provisioning profile and Certificate.
4. Add Provisioning Profile to your project.

   5. while creating provisioning profile you need to add device uuid.

Follow above steps. I am sure your problem will solve.

Comment: This is correct Answer please follow the steps your problem get solved

Comment: If you not register for ios Developer Program you are not able to distribute app.For App distribution you have to download distribution certificate and add it to your project.