# How do I sign my iOS application when I don't have an iPhone?

Tags: ios, xcode

I followed the steps listed here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW1

And when I attempted to create the team provisioning profile, I ran into this error message: `"Unable to create a provisioning profile because your team has no devices registered in the Member Center. Please connect a device, enable it for development, and add it to the Member Center using the Organizer."`

So is it possible to launch an app to the app store without owning (and thereby registering) an iOS unit?

If so, how do I move forwards?

Comment: Are you trying to create a development profile or a deployment profile?

Comment: I suppose a deployment profile, I'm just trying to roll the app out

Comment: I don't recall having to choose over the process - what would I be doing differently?

Comment: Looking at that documentation, it looks like the Xcode process does them together but if you go to the [Member Center](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/) you should be able to create an App Store deployment certificate and a provisioning profile to go with it.

Comment: @BrianNickel Sorry, I didn't mention that I already did that. The above message stays the same. Is it a must to own an iOS device (or at least register one) like the error message indicates before generating a release build?

Comment: if you are deploying for development (among your test team, or on your test device), then you need to create a "Development Provisioning Profile", which will have the device id listed in it. If you are trying to release the app in the app store, then you'll need a "Release / App Store Provisioning Profile", which doesn't need a device listed in it.

Comment: @NitinAlabur When I attempt to sign the app in XCode, it seems to require both - a Development Provisioning Profile which requires a registered device, as well as the latter. How do I work around this?

Comment: @NitinAlabur it seems that I must at least have one to register the device here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28488373/how-to-select-a-team-when-xcode-thinks-im-not-a-registered-ios-developer-als?rq=1

Can someone clarify that this is indeed required?

Comment: interesting. I have never released an app that never required a device to be added to the provisioning profile or have it on the device list before submitting to app store. (whats stopping you from adding a device to it though?)

Comment: @NitinAlabur Haha - the fact that I only own an Android. I am borrowing one from a friend to carry out the rest of the process - the point of asking this question was to gauge whether there was a way around it. Thanks for confirming this though!

Comment: Would be great if you can answer your own question, if just adding a device solves your problem.